# i18n URL Parameter Encoding for REST Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, url-encoding

In our **Rails REST API** we need to get an object by (unique) name. The name can consist of any, and especially cyrillic, characters. My first attempt was the following:

`GET /api/objects/name/:name`

An alternative would be:

`GET /api/objects?name=:name`

In both cases, `:name` can consist of any characters and needs to respect correct encoding. I have green rspec tests running with *Тест Веселье 123* for example, but I worry that there may be **edge cases that don’t encode correctly**.

What is the correct way to avoid URL parameter encoding issues for GET requests with a Rails backend? Can the issue be avoided altogether? Is there a solution to sufficiently test encoding edge cases?

Comment: Hello, did you ever find a solution? I am expecting Cyrillic letters in the URL as well, and I would like to find a solution as well. If I find something I will post back here. Cheers! - Misha

Comment: @MishaP I’ve chosen to avoid the issue by restricting valid characters for the only request that this was necessary, and use IDs for all other requests. 

That being said, I suspect that rails uses [URI::Escape](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html) for encoding/decoding, which is very solid from my experience. I recommend writing specs that cover such cases (e.g. sending of all cyrillic characters) in any case.